# Why do these strategies for picking a random chapter in a book differ?

Tags: probability

A book has 10 short and 10 long chapters. Short chapters span 10 pages, and long chapters span 20 pages.

Why does the probability that you will pick a long or a short chapter differ between these  strategies?

Strategy #1: Flip to a random page, back up to the start of that chapter, and start reading.
Strategy #2: Flip to a random page, go forward to the start of the next chapter, and start reading (and pick the first chapter if the page you pick lies within the last chapter).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The book has 300 pages, 200 of which are in long chapters and 100 of which are in short chapters.  If you pick a random page it is $\frac 23$ to be in a long chapter.  So strategy 1 gives you a long chapter $\frac 23$ of the time.  Strategy 2 gives you the chapter after a long one $\frac 23$ of the time.  If the chapters alternate, strategy 2 will give you a short chapter $\frac 23$ of the time.

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't the book still have 200 pages from long and 100 pages from short chapters both ways? How come the probability of picking long chapters isn't $\frac{2}{3}$ for both strategies? In other words, doesn't that logic for strategy 1 also also apply to 2?

Comment: The initial page selection is in fact $\frac 23$ to be in a long chapter either way.  But the selected chapter in strategy 2 is not the chapter the selected page is in.  Think of a 2 chapter book with the first chapter 200 pages and the second 100.  $\frac 23$ of the time the page chosen will be in chapter 1.  In strategy 1 you then read chapter 1.  In strategy 2 you then read chapter 2.

Comment: Ah thanks. So if short and long chapters alternate, then a reader using strategy 2 flips forward to a short chapter if he/she lands in a long chapter. However, what if the chapters don't alternate and are ordered randomly? Would the probability of reading a short chapter for strategy 2 be less than $\frac{2}{3}$ because the reader will not always move forward to a short chapter after landing in a long chapter?

Comment: It will depend upon the ordering of the chapters.  If chapters 1-5 are long and 2-6 are short, you will have $\frac 2{15}$ to read any of 2-6 and $\frac 1{15}$ to read 1 or 7-10.  So that is $\frac 9{15}$ to read a long and $\frac 6{15}$ to read a short.

Comment: @DavidFaux: If the chapters are in random order, and you land in a long chapter, the probability the next one is long is $\frac{9}{19}$, while if you land in a short, probability next is long is $\frac{10}{19}$. So the probability you end up in a long with second strategy and random chapter order is $\frac{2}{3}\frac{9}{19}+\frac{1}{3}\frac{10}{19}=\frac{28}{57}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas:  Right you are.  OP didn't say the chapters are in random order, but that is another way to see the difference.

Comment: @RossMillikan: He didn't in the main post, but did ask the question, third comment from the top, second sentence. I was just answering that, definitely not the question in the main post, which had been fully dealt with by your answer.

Comment: @AndréNicolas:  Your logic makes it clear that there is a difference between (if there are two things, a and b) pick a random item-what is the chance of a and pick a random item and look at something else-what is the chance of a?

Comment: Thanks a lot friends! Just curious, where did $\frac{9}{19}$ and $\frac{10}{19}$ come from?

Comment: @DavidFaux:  If you leave a chapter, there are 19 chapters that could be the next one.  9 of them are the length of the one you are in (because the next one can't be the one you are in) and 10 are the other length.  So it is $\frac 9{19}$ that the chapter after a long one is long.